# PHP - localization - translation works in one php file but not in another

Tags: php, gettext, hebrew

In need help to resolve this mystery:
I am using XAMPP on a windows machine and use the "echo _("message")" way to translate into Hebrew.
Locale directory is on `root/locale/Hebrew_Israel.1255/LC_MESSAGES`

Translation works fine on the index.php file located in the site root.

However, translation doesn't work on another php file located under /php directory.
You would guess it is due to relative path issues but it fails to translate even if I put it root.

I am not sure how Locale works and what all these lines mean. Couldn't find proper documentation. 
Am I suppose to run it every php or just once?

Anyway, this is my "config.php" file which I include before each php file, notice path is absolute.

```
// language stuff:
$locale = "Hebrew_Israel.1255"; // this might change on server 
$domain = "messages";
putenv("LANG=$locale");
putenv("LANGUAGE=$locale");
putenv("LC_ALL={$locale}"); // Returns TRUE
putenv("LC_MESSAGES=$locale");
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/locale";
bindtextdomain($domain, $path);
textdomain($domain);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use $_SESSION for the locale and pass it as $_GET if you want to switch.

For example, a webpage I'm using in Spanish and English has this:

In my header.php

```
    session_start();

    if(!$_GET["locale"] || $_GET["locale"] == "es_LA")
    {
        $_SESSION["locale"] = "es_LA";
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION["locale"] = $_GET["locale"];
    }

    putenv("LC_ALL=".$_SESSION["locale"].".utf8");
    setlocale(LC_ALL, $_SESSION["locale"].".utf8");
    bindtextdomain("messages", "./locale");
    bind_textdomain_codeset("messages", "UTF-8");
    textdomain("messages");
```

So if this is your default language you need to pass your file the locale variable. If you're handling .htaccess the easiest way is:

.htaccess file

```
RewriteRule         ^/                  index.php?locale=es_LA  [L]
RewriteRule         ^en/                index.php?locale=en_US  [L]
```

Now I'm no pro using gettext but this one has worked for me.

Comment: Hi mihali_ov, 
I mananged to tackle the problem: it was that annoying php cashing. I had to restart the php-server (apache) and it worked.

Comment: @HananShteingart you should try the $_SESSION handling of the locale

Answer (score 0):

Solved: it was that annoying caching going on. 
I had to restart the apache server and it works :-)